# If $Q_l \in ℝ^{m\times l}$, why does $Q_lQ_l^T \in ℝ^{m\times m}$ have nullity $m-l$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $Q_l \in ℝ^{m\times l}$ is a matrix that is the first $l$ columns of $Q \in ℝ^{m\times m}$ where Q is orthogonal, why does $Q_lQ_l^T \in ℝ^{m\times m}$ have nullity $m-l$?

The nullspace of $Q_lQ_l^T$ is {$x: Q_lQ_l^Tx=0$}

Since $Q_lQ_l^T=I$ why is the nullity not $0$?

Also if $A \in ℝ^{m\times n} , m\ge n$ why is $\|Q_l^TA\|_2 = \|A\|_2$ only if $l=m$?

I know that since $Q_lQ_l^T=I  \implies \|Q_l\|_2=1$ and so $\|Q_l^TA\|_2 \le \|A\|_2$

Comment: The dimension of the nullspace is also called nullity

Comment: The nullity of $I$ is $0$

Comment: Was a typo my bad

Answer (score 1):

$Q_lQ_l^T\ne I_m$. Observe however that $Q_l^TQ_l=I_l$, using that $Q$ was orthogonal. Thus the rank of $Q_l$ must be at least $l$, however since it is an $m\times l$ matrix, it has rank at most $l$ at the same time.

**Edit:**
I mistakenly wrote $Q_l$ has nullity $m-l$. That was wrong. It has rank $l$ and therefore nullity $0$ by rank-nullity. It is $Q_l^T$ that has nullity $m-l$, also by rank-nullity (since matrices and their transposes have the same rank).

Then $Q_lQ_l^T$ has nullity $m-l$ since it is the product of an injective matrix and a matrix with nullity $m-l$.

Comment: Why is the last line true?

Comment: @pablo_mathscobar Sorry, I was careless. I've edited to fix.

Comment: Why is $Q_l$ an injective matrix?

Comment: @pablo_mathscobar, because its nullity is 0

Comment: Oh thanks makes sense